# Recursive Set in Partial Computable Function Problem

Tags: computability

Suppose $A, B, C$ are disjoint set such as shown on this figure. $f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x)$ is partially computable function.

[image]

why $A,B,C$ is recursive set?

Comment: Every recursive set is in particular recursively enumerable. So if it is true that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are recursive, then the answer to "why not r.e?" is: "They are!"

Comment: so if A, B, C be r.e so they are be recursive?

Comment: No, there are r.e. sets that are not recursive.

Comment: can you say what the up arrows and the tiny circle mean ?

Comment: in the above example we can say every partial computable function is recursive set?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Things seem to make sense if $\uparrow$ means "undefined" (remember these are _partial_ computable functions), and $\circ$ is taken to mean zero. If this is a scan from user153695's textbook, it has really awful typography...

Comment: i means can we say every partial computable function is recursive set?

Comment: @user153695: You have written that comment several times. It doesn't make sense -- a partial computable function is a _function_, which is a different thing from a _set_ (unless we're doing axiomatic set theory and identifying a function with its graph, but that's not what we're doing here). A partial computable function is a _function_ and therefore not a _set_, and therefore, in particular, not a recursive set.

Comment: Even if we _are_ considering a function to be the set $\{(x,y)\mid f(x)=y\}$ the set that represents an arbitrary partial recursive function is not a recursive set. A counterexample would be $$f(n)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{program $n$ halts}\\ \uparrow & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Run $f_1, f_2, f_3$ in parallel.

- If $x \in A$ then $f_1(x) = 1$ and $f_3(x) = \circ$.
- If $x \in B$ then $f_1(x) = 1$ and $f_2(x) = \circ$.
- If $x \in C$ then $f_1(x) = 2$.
- If $x \notin A \cup B \cup C$ then $f_2(x) =  f_3(x) = \circ$.

Therefore after a finite amount of time you will be able to distinguish the four cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just write down what each of your $f_i$ functions does to each kind of input:

$$\begin{array}{r|ccc} x & f_1(x) & f_2(x) & f_3(x) \\ \hline
\in A & 1 & \uparrow & 0 \\
\in B & 1 & 0 & \uparrow \\
\in C & 2 & \uparrow & \uparrow \\
\notin(A\cup B\cup C) & \uparrow & 0 & 0 
\end{array} $$

So if you have an unknown input, just run all of $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ on it in parallel until *either* two of them have halted, *or* $f_1$ returns $2$. One of these will always happen, and what you know at that time will allow you to know exactly which line of the table you're in.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am assuming the up arrow means that the computation diverges and that the tiny circle is a zero. All sets are recursive. From the functions we have enumerations of $C$ and $A\cup B$ (from $f_1$), enumerations of $\neg (A\cup C)$ and  $\neg (B\cup C)$, the complements.

If $n$ is iin $A$ it will occur in the enumeration of $A\cup B$ and the enumeration of  $\neg (B\cup C)$, all such common elements are in $A$. If $n$ is not in $A$ it will occur in the list of $C$ or $\neg (A\cup C)$.

A similar situation holds for $B$.

For $C$ if an element is in the list of $C$, then its in $C$, if $n$ is not in $C$ it occurs on one of the lists of $\neg (A\cup C)$ or  $\neg (B\cup C)$.